# How to draw a non-defect transparent line?

Tags: gimp, transparency, tools

Gimp is pretty good to draw a straight lines. It is easy as 1) set first point with left click and 2) set second point with shift+left click:

[image]
[image]
[image]

But when I set opaque to 30-70%, small defect is appeared - first dot is overlaid on my line:
[image]

How do I deal with this?
One another example of this trouble is:

[image]

instead of something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can draw the line that you want on a dedicated layer with 100% opacity, then set the layer at 70% opacity or as you like.

Comment: nice workaround.

Comment: You can also paint with 100% opacity on a layer set to 70% opacity.

Answer (score 0):

For a quick line here or there, another way is to select your tool (eg: the paint tool), place the dot, -UNDO-, then hit <kbd>shift</kbd> and make the line. You will need to select another tool, then come back to the tool again in order to repeat this process. Use Mario's method for anything requiring the lines to intersect or many lines.